# Is it possible to move the Validation Panel in SurveyJS below each question in the designer?

Tags: surveyjs

I am trying to see if its possible to have the validation panel (the one that usually shows up on the right side of the editor with options like Required Error message etc) show below each question in the designer tab.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no option to move the validation panel below a question element on a design surface. Survey element properties are located in the right-side property grid panel.
As an option, you can add a [custom adorner action](https://surveyjs.io/survey-creator/examples/create-custom-adorners/reactjs) which would activate a property grid's Validation category.

By the way, I'm curious as to why you wish to display the validation panel below a question? Please elaborate on your usage scenario.